# Is this the most optimal way to make the navbar display which page is currently active?

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to add the functionality which shows which page is currently active in the navbar. I read some stuff on stack overflow and found 2 solutions which work and are understandable, however, I would still like to know if they are correct/optimal or if there is an even better way.

The first way is using this:

```
<li class='{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('signInView') ? 'currentURL' : '' }}'><a href="{{ route('signInView') }}">Sign In</a></li>
<li class='{{ Route::currentRouteNamed('signUpView') ? 'currentURL' : '' }}'><a href="{{ route('signUpView') }}">Sign Up</a></li>
```

The second way is using this:

```
<li class='{{ Request::is('/signin') ? 'currentURL' : '' }}'><a href="{{ route('signInView') }}">Sign In</a></li>
<li class='{{ Request::is('/signup') ? 'currentURL' : '' }}'><a href="{{ route('signUpView') }}">Sign Up</a></li>
```

Both ways seems extremely similar to me. The first one works only if I have named my routes (as I have) and the second one just uses the current URL. I'm currently feeling the first approach better.

Now my question is whether are are better ways to accomplish this. Some that may require less repetitive code maybe? Are there any drawbacks to these approaches?

Comment: Its better to name your route. Route url can change but the name is a reference point to places in the code so you don't have to look for places where you use a route path but just change the name. On the other side, your question is asking for opinions and I remember this doesn't look like a problem to be solved.

Comment: My question is if there are any better ways to tackle this problem that what I've used so far.

Comment: If you understand it is correct for you. If there is something worth optimizing it is probably not this. I normally pass in the page I am on via the rout and then if in each of the nav item for that word. Might be cheaper than the method call

Comment: @Bobimaru This is absolutely good in terms of efficiency. No need to optimize further. You will hardly have a 100-120 links in your links collection. This check happens pretty fast and you won't see any difference in terms of UX. Although, there is a scope to shorten your blade code if there are many links you need to show. Put all routes in an array and run a foreach loop on this array and add the link inside it with it's respective placeholders.